# Can I control VirtualBox guests' network access via NAT on Linux?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, firewall, nat

I'm using VirtualBox as a VM provider for Vagrant, where as an admin I've installed both as packages on a CentOS 7.2 system. I broadly trust the security of the host OS, but the purpose of these VMs is to give people the ability to be root and experiment with Linux in a fairly safe environment.

I've blacklisted the `vboxnetflt` kernel module, and now you can't start a VM with bridged networking, which leaves the user with the option of networks that don't connect outside the host, or NAT. When using NAT on a VM, though, there's no interface on the host system I can firewall, and I'd like to provide only a whitelist of systems the guests can talk to.

(Obviously, there's no inbound access from outside the host, but it's outbound connections I'm worried about here.)

What's the best way to restrict what these guests can talk to, given that I can't enforce control on the contents of the guest?

Comment: But are you interested in letting thru communications with many many hosts, or just a small number?

Comment: Relatively small - repo servers mainly for updates via yum.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I control VirtualBox guests' network access via NAT on Linux?

No you cannot: packet analysis via *tcpdump* shows clearly that outgoing packets carry no trace of their origin (from the host/from the guest), so there is no easy way to distinguish the two.

What you can do is to use *Host-only adapter* instead of NAT, enabling the DHCP server, and then add the following line to the */etc/rc.local* file of every VM (I'll tell you how to do that in a sec):

```
ip route add default via 192.168.56.1
```

and to issue the following commands on the host:

```
 echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o YourMainInterface -j MASQUERADE
```

where *YourMainInterface = eth0, wlan0,...*, whatever.

In order to produce identical BMs, just configure **one** to your liking, save it as an OVA file via *File -> Export Appliance*, then reimport it changing the MAC addresses of all interface (one simple, automatic option at the time *importing Appliance*).

Now the host has an interface, called by default *vbonet0*, on which you can activate the firewall:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o vboxnet0 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -o vboxnet0 -d AllowedIpAddress -j ACCEPT 
iptables -P OUTPUT -o vboxnet0 DROP
```

Comment: The difficulty is that I don't control the contents of the VM. I want to prevent careless (or possibly malicious) users who have root on a VM being able to spam our network. If it's possible to restrict VMs that they've created to be in host-only mode (or alternatively just disable NAT), then this might be doable.I've already removed the vboxnetflt kernel module to stop them using bridging.